# Date format issue, google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a column contain a date in **"Sep -13"** format.

When I access it from code, it gives integer value. How can I get a date object?

If I use **"dd/mm/yyyy"** format in sheet, it gives me date object.

```
function check()
{
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('sheet id');
  var sourcesheet = source.getSheetByName('sheet name');   
  var tt = sourcesheet.getRange('F700').getValue();
   debugger;
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: I tried replicating your issue.  If I click the column heading, and make the entire column a date format, I get a date in the code.  If I format the entire column as a number, I get a number.  So, I was not able to duplicate your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That cells original value might be an integer. That could be happen if you copy and paste values only for a date. so `.getValue()` will give you that number.

You can use that number to create a date object. JavaScript dates can be constructed by passing milliseconds

```
//base date 01/01/1970 integer value :25569 
//excelDate your date in integer

var myDate = new Date((excelDate - 25569)*86400*1000);
```